# regasm RA0000: No types were registered

Tags: .net, c++-cli, regasm

I have a C++/CLI assembly (compiled for .NET 3.5 that comes with Windows 7).
The assembly is marked as `ComVisible(true)`. It contains 2 classes and 1 interface. Both classes are marked as `ComVisible(false)` so they shouldn't matter. The interface is marked with `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType::InterfaceIsIUnknown)` and a specific GUID. This interface needs to be registered.

When I try to register this assembly using `RegAsm.exe AssemplyName`, I get this warning:

```
RegAsm : warning RA0000 : No types were registered
```

My assembly depends on 3 other assemblies which are in the same directory as my main assembly. 2 of them register with no problems and the 3rd is not marked as `ComVisible`.

Any ideas why I'm unable to register my assembly?

Comment: Yep, the interface was public. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the assembly wasn't being registered because it didn't contain any classes available for registration, just the one interface. As soon as I added a dummy class to the assembly, the warning went away and the assembly got registered.

Comment: Where i want to add dummy Class?

Comment: Just add a dummy class to your project.