# How do you develop a C# dll in Visual Studio 2010 that can be registered on another pc via regasm?

Tags: c#, regasm, dllregistration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regasm RA0000: No types were registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054039/regasm-ra0000-no-types-were-registered)

I have a fairly simple component, strongly named and built into a dll file.

I give that file to a co-worker to register on his Windows 7 machine.

He uses the command: (from the location he has copied the file to)

```
regasm mycontrol.dll
```

And gets the reply

> RegAsm : warning RA0000 : No types were registered.

Why?

Comment: And does this component actually *expose* some COM interfaces? Is it COMVisible? Without your code, it's kind of hard to know...

Comment: Did you set `ComVisible` property to `true` in `assemblyInfo.cs`?  Are any of the classes `ComVisible`?

Comment: Are you sure your classes are public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anyone actually developed a C# dll in Visual Studio 2010 that could be registered on another pc via regasm?

Yes, someone has done it.

Look at [the documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx) on creating an interop DLL to see if there's a step you may have missed.  A common problem is forgetting to set the `ComVisible` property to `true` in `assemblyInfo.cs`.

Some key sections:

[Packaging an Assembly for COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx)

[Qualifying .NET Types for Interoperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fcfby2t.aspx)