# Excel doesn't see DLL

Tags: json, excel, dll

I have created DLL in .Net that, in turn, uses NewsoftJson and RestSharp DLLs. 
I have compiled it as COM-compatible, registered it using regasm and calling it from Excel. Excel sees it and connects with it without problems. This part is good.

On my computer, where I have VS installed everything works fine but on other computers I have a problem: when I call a method that is using objects from NewsoftJson/RestSharp DLLs I get "File not found" error. The DLLs themselves are present in both local folder and in System32. 
How do I make them visible to Excel?

Comment: have you used regsrv32 to register the dlls?

Comment: SeanC, they are not COM DLLs so I cannot register them with regsvr32. Getting "The entry point DllRegisterServer was not found". If I use regasm I get "no types were registered"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161384/how-do-you-develop-a-c-sharp-dll-in-visual-studio-2010-that-can-be-registered-on

Comment: Manuell, that article is not helpfull, my DLL is already COM-compatible and can be registered. But some of its methods use third-party DLLs like Newtonsoft.Json so Excel doesn't see them on another computer.