# Running RegAsm From C#

Tags: c#, processstartinfo, running-other-programs

That's my code:

```
        Process regAsmProcess = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo Process_Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Process_Info.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\Regasm.exe";
        Process_Info.Arguments = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\myDLL.dll";
        Process_Info.Verb = "runas";
        regAsmProcess.StartInfo = Process_Info;
        regAsmProcess.Start();
```

I also added a .manifest file to the project running this code and set:

```
requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"
```

It's not a path issue, the dll to be registered is in the same folder as the program calling regAsm.
It doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How about [`RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.registrationservices.registerassembly(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723369/regasm-unregister-issue
it may help you!